# expand an collapse button in datagrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

how  to make an button  in datagrid expand an collapse where there  will be  2 image buttons

once user clicks the button the rows under it will expand where there should be an one image button with (- symbol)

again user clicks the same row the rows which were expanded  should collapse.(+ image  button)

here  i have done the function for  doing the  expand and collapse is  completed. now only i need add an image  which will change once the user clicks the row either ( we can do it by javascript or in code behind ?)

how can i change the image button like that

can any one tell me how i should  i ahead  or any code that can help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Boolean you can bind to, the best way is to include both images and bind their visibilities to a boolean.  Just make their visibilities inverses of each other.

Comment: thanks  for teh  replay stephan,
 this is what my code looks in xaml file once i click the button there  should be an change in the image that is  with ("+" and"-")